# NuGet Errors After Upgrading to ASP.NET Core 2.0

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I upgraded my ASP.NET Core 1.1 web app to ASP.NET Core 2.0 following this article:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/

I followed each step and now I'm getting NuGet errors -- see below:
[image]

Any idea why?

Comment: Can please add the project csproj content?

Comment: In the `csproj` file, I removed all individual package references for ASP.NET Core and Entity Framework Core and added `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.0" />` as suggested in this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/. That seems to have fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to the latest stable version of Visual Studio 2017 15.7.1 fixed the issues for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced a similar issue. Please try one of the few:

1. Clean solution, delete all bin and obj folders in the solution folder, Rebuild
2. Upgrade Visual Studio
3. Delete all from the %temp% folder. (This worked for me)